# No matching function for call to 'Random'

Tags: c++, функции, циклы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int Random(int min, int max) {
    return min + rand() % (max - min);
}

int main () {
    Random();
}
```

Почему не компилируется я же всё вроде бы (но это не точно) грамотно написал

Comment: Так у вас функция рандом хочет 2 параметра принять. Нужно вызывать, к примеру, Random(5, 10);

Comment: Для `std::rand` нужен `<cstdlib>`, а не `<cmath>`. `<cmath>` вам тут ни к чему. Как, впрочем и все остальное, что вы уже понавключали.

Answer (score 0):

Функция Random должна возвращать значение типа int в переменную, а так же имеет аргументы, которые вы не передаете.

```
int result = 0;
result = Random(1, 10);
```

Comment: Ну, допустим, "возвращать в переменную" - условие не обязательное...

Comment: если не возвращать значение, в данном контексте, то функция бесполезна

Comment: Это - совершенно другой вопрос, касающийся семантики, а не синтаксиса.

Comment: с научной точки зрения правы)